# How to get the link from a clickable element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to download CSV files from a website. this is why i use the the `click()` command from selenium.

[image: image description here]

Elements have the following structure

[image]

---

## code

```
 csvList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("csv")
    for l in csvlist:
           if 'error' not in l.text and 'after' not in l.text:
               #get link here
               l.click()
```

---

## Question

My question is how can we get the **download link** from the element before I download it? the link that pointed to by the black arrow in the picture.

When I use **l.get_attribute('href')** it gives me None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element `l` in `csvList`, get the parent element by xpath and then get that element's `href`:

```
csvList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("csv")
for l in csvlist:
       if 'error' not in l.text and 'after' not in l.text:
           currentLink = l.find_element_by_xpath("..")
           href = currentLink.get_attribute("href")
```

**Note**: If you do a .click() in this loop and the link takes you to a new page, you will get a StaleElementException for each click after the first. In that case, extract each href and save to a collection. Then navigate to each href (URL) in the collection.

Comment: I am getting the following error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'**

Comment: I updated my answer to show the code in the loop you provided. Also, I had 'find_elements' and not 'find_element' so I changed that too.

Comment: yes well it's the same thing it's ok.  File **"QL2scrape.py", line 84, in <module>
    href = currentLink.get_attribute("href")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute''''**

Comment: do u think it is getting all the parents? should I use currentLink[0].get_attribute?

Comment: Not sure. Best thing to do is `print` them and see.

Answer (score 1):

The div does not have the href attribute. Its parent the "a" tag does. I would use xpath.

```
By.XPath("//a[/div[@class='csv']]")
```

Comment: can I still click on the link later on?

Comment: Yeah, so you can do what Timothy Cope suggests. Or you can use this in the FindElements Method to find the links. Then you can click them in your for loop.

Comment: i think it should **browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="csv"]/parent::a')** right?